# How should you go about learning ASP.NET after life as a ColdFusion developer?

Tags: asp.net, coldfusion

As someone who has spent around 10 years programming web applications with Adobe's ColdFusion, I have decided to add ASP.NET as a string to my bow.

For someone who has spent so long with CF and the underlying Java, ASP.NET seems a little alien to me.  How should I go about getting up to speed with ASP.NET so that I can be truly dangerous with it?  Do I need to know C# at any great amount of detail?

I want to be in a position where I can build basic web apps fairly quickly so I can learn more doing the tricky stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm only maybe six months down the same path, but here are some thoughts from my experience so far:

The C# language shouldn't give you much problem if you have very much experience with Java at all (or even CFScript).  As a reference, though, when I was starting, I found [csharp-station](http://www.csharp-station.com/) a good primer for language basics.  It won't help you much as far as the ASP.NET side goes; but it is good for syntax.  More you'll be familiarizing yourself with the .NET libraries.  The IDE actually can be an enormous help here.

Here are the three biggest differences I found making the transition:

1. **ASP.NET Server Controls** - In ColdFusion, you really have pretty
   direct control over the HTML; you
   work very closely with the page. 
   This isn't so much the case in
   ASP.NET.  The server controls are
   meant to relieve you of a lot of the
   tedium, but at a cost of maybe some
   direct control.  As a CF programmer,
   I'm very particular about what gets
   actually output to the browser; and
   at first ASP.NET frustrated me
   because it spits out a lot of extra
   code.  Still, the controls are
   really powerful, and it pays to
   familiarize yourself with them. 
   Form and validation controls,
   especially, save you from a lot of
   the tedium in CF of handling post
   back and validation.  W3Schools
   actually has a decent [list of web
   server controls](https://web.archive.org/web/20080829141718/https://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_refwebcontrols.asp).
2. **The page model** - ColdFusion is pretty agnostic in terms of page
   flow.  ASP.NET is very much geared
   towards using post backs, and is
   very event driven.  If you're not
   using a framework with CF (e.g.
   Model Glue), this may be foreign to
   you.  .NET takes care of handling a
   lot of the post back behavior for
   you.  Also, not to say that
   ColdFusion can't be object and
   function driven by good use of
   CFC's, but ASP.NET really tries to
   push you down the OO path compared
   to CF in my experience.
3. **Database access** - Using ASP.NET really made me appreciate how
   powerful cfquery really is.  The
   csharp-station site also has a good
   tutorial on working with the native
   .NET db tools.  I haven't worked on
   enough projects yet to start looking
   around for DB access extensions; I'm
   pretty sure Jeff recommended
   something that they used for
   building this site, so you might
   check that out.  Otherwise, I really
   suggest you familiarize yourself
   with the DataSet object.  It's
   somewhat similar to a query object
   in CF, and lets you run query of
   queries, etc...  Looping over
   queries in CF is very common, but it
   doesn't happen nearly as much in
   ASP.NET because of data binding.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a video called [ASP.NET for ColdFusion developers](http://www.asp.net/Learn/videos/video-27.aspx) you may be interested in.

Edit, [here's another](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-28.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET is a core concept, and I would really recommend taking a course in it. Having a qualified instructor explain exactly what the differences are between a DataSet, DataReader (and so forth -- there are a **lot** of different data access object types) is ***invaluable***. Not to mention you'll better understand the appropriate time and place to use each; and you can ask questions and get immediate answers in a classroom setting.

I took an ADO.NET class (one night a week, about 8 weeks) at my local university for around $400. Even if my company hadn't paid for it, I would have been happy to, and I can highly recommend anyone trying to learn .NET do the same.