# Migrating from ColdFusion to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, coldfusion, migration

One my client has his website developed using coldfusion... Now I want to migrate that website from `coldfusion to asp.net`... As a web developer i know it is possible,but want to know a few things

- Challenges/Learning curves involved in migrating from `coldfusion to asp.net`...
- What are the factors i have to watch out for during migration?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768/how-should-you-go-about-learning-asp-net-after-life-as-a-coldfusion-developer

Comment: @jorn i am an asp.net developer not a coldfusion developer...

Comment: What are the reasons for the rewrite? I don't mean to sound harsh here but is the site having issues or are you going to charge him for a rewrite away from a language he knows just because you don't know or like CF? Have you looked at Blue Dragon, a CF engine that runs on the .net platform? http://www.newatlanta.com/products/bluedragon/j2ee_dotnet.cfm

Comment: I would read Joel Spolsky's article on why re-writing a working code base from scratch is the worst thing you can do for any project and greatly increases the chances of the software failing because of not understanding the data, details and how they work together, and why.  If you rewrite something, misinterpretations will happen.  If you take the time to learn the code and data, you will be able to work in it anyways. ColdFusion is the most advanced, and easiest language to learn.  If you know HTML + how to think algorithms, you know 85% of the language already..

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suprisingly enough this is a situation that I have toyed with so herewith are some tips.

- As you probably figured out after maybe having looked at the CF code - everything language construct is prefixed with `cf` (I guess this may be some not so suttle way of Adobe advertising...)
- **Architecture** Determine the architecture of the existing CF app. eg .Is it MVC based using a framework such as Fusebox. The reason imo for this is that it can guide you towards what the outcome of the asp system should be architecturally.
- **Language/Syntax considerations** - CF is pretty easy to understand and if you dont the Adobe online reference is there. CFC's (ColdFusion Components) are analogous to classes.
- **Variables** - watch out here. I have been burnt many times when working on CF apps. Knowing whats a string vs an int.
- **Web Services** - CF allows for very easy declaration/creation of webservices. Check all your `cffucntion` properties to identify them (`access="remote"`)
- **`cfquery`** - The worst and best thing about CF imo is  `cfquery`. Not the function itself but rather how its used within the current application. CF has no restrictions on what you can do and where you can it so could find random queries scattered throughout the app. This is a double edged <del>function</del> sword.

The above noted are as a result of having worked on a badly designed CF app. However, in terms of functionality and operability - it's rich, full of features and a pleasure to work with.

---

**EDIT**

I found the following resources which may be of interest if you have not found it already

- [Migrating from ColdFusion to ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479305.aspx)

---

If I think of anything more I will update..

Comment: The "cf" prefixes predate Adobe's ownership of CF, and Macromedia's. They're just a way of differentiating CF tags from HTML tags. In fact, one of the early alphas of CF was called "Horizon" and all the tags were prefixed with "hz". When CF 1.0 was released, all tags had "db" prefixes, which were changed to the present "cf" prefix in CF 2.0, when Allaire still owned the product.